# Lazy loading from subclass in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If I make `@x` lazily loaded in the parent class `A` it can be called and initialized just fine, but if I try to call it from `A`'s subclass `B`, then it won't call `@x`'s initialization method and returns `nil`. Why is that?

```
class A
  def x
    @x ||= 'x'
  end
end

puts A.new.x # 'x'

class B < A
  def use_x
    puts @x.inspect # nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `x` instead of directly accessing the instance variable `@a`.

```
class B < A
  def use_x
    puts x.inspect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the method `x` is not called within `use_x`. Whether it is `A` or `B` is irrelevant. `puts B.new.x` would give the same result as it would with `puts A.new.x`.